# Flash/AIR Stage Video on iOS - Is It Possible? How is the performance?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, video, air

Does any of you can point me to some resource about video performance of AIR (3.2) on iOS devices.

I am interested into:

- is StageVideo available
- is video streaming allowed/enabled
- is the performance ok with high definition videos?
- is .flv playback allowed? (how about on android: flash is there already)

Comment: Just +1ed this, I've been working on an app using the zebra crossing QR code reader and am curious about iOS compatibility with stage video and AIR 3.2 as well for bitmap capture from the stage video.  If I end up not seeing an answer and getting around to testing this out with some co-workers I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: Thanks @shaunhusain, I would also love to test this but the problem is that I do not own so many mobile devices and certificates so I can make a serious testing over several screen resolutions/cpu/gpu. Soon I will add a bounty to this, in case you decide to test it. :)

Comment: I have worked on a streaming video application for iOS (iPad2) and I must say I was rather surprised by the performance. We were able to get a HD (not full HD, but something like 1024 by 768) video stream playing with no hiccups whatsoever.
Don't know about .flv Playback though. We also encountered a nasty bug that didn't allow us to stream via RTMPS/RTMPE.

Comment: @DennisJaamann Thanks for your comment. Indeed it is interesting to hear such nice news from you. One question: did you used stage video or normal video ?

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu, We used StageVideo for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Only H264 has hardware decoding on iOS.
This means comparable video performance with native player only for H264
and slugish (at best) decoding for Sorenson and VP6 (even with low resolutions).

*"AIR 3 for iOS uses the StageVideo object for H.264 video with hardware decoding, with limited supported for NetStream functionality. AIR 3 for iOS also supports On2 and Sorenson codecs through the StageVideo object. This support does not use hardware decoding, and it does not limit NetStream functionality."*
 **[flash.media.StageVideo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html)**

FLV and MP4 are encapsulation formats.
FLV can contain VP6+MP3 or H264+AAC (or any of them taken alone).
MP4 can contain H264+AAC.
The docs don't say anything about FLV not beeing supported on iOS.

However, on iOS, if FLV/H264 won't play, you won't be able to remux it to MP4 on the fly because of the following restriction (otherwise you would lose hardware decoding):
*"Note: This method is not supported for H.264 video in AIR 3.0 for iOS."*
 **[flash.net.NetStream::appendBytes()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes%28%29)**

Nothing is said about Sorenson or VP6 not beeing suported for on the fly remuxing (thus they should be).

You shouldn't need appendBytes anyways, unless you plan on doing some very advanced stuff, like switching bitrates on the fly without any interruption during play.

Live streaming requires something similar of what appendBytes does. Since H264 hardware decoding is required and does not have a software mode, you won't get H264 for live streams.

*"It turns out that real-time streaming of an H264 video does not render on iOS devices in Adobe Air.  Other video codecs will work (H263), but not for H264.  You'll consume the feed, but will only hear audio.  I confirmed this after talking with members of the Adobe Air development team."*
From [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4336274)

How well H264 decoding performs on different Apple ARM CPUs really depends a lot on video encode settings (B-frames or keyframes, bitrates, etc.) and wether you have dynamic content, static content, fast switching scenes, resolution, color palletes, etc.

Conclusion:
Use FLV or MP4 (whichever suits you best), with H264+AAC inside.
Experiment with encode settings, or lots of videos of which you are targeting (if any).
Determine which is the lowest (oldest) iOS device you want to target, and test on that.

Comment: Forgot to mention all of the above apply only to StageVideo, never to normal flash.media.Video.

Comment: Hi Tiberiu, your post answers more of my questions. Thanks for posting. I will mark you as correct. Just one more question: how is the performance? it is lagging or running ok in native resolution ?

Comment: It has to be the same as with QuickTime. Depends a lot on the video beeing played and at the same time, on the hardware.

Comment: When compiling the AIR app you must target at least -swf-version=13 (StageVideo became available with -swf-version=11, however, I recommend targeting the newest supported, I think its 15 now). If FLV with H264/AAC doesn't cut it to hardware, an MP4 with the same streams must. Check bitrates and recommended video and audio encode settings for various iOS devices before doing any tests (that is if you have control on the video beeing played). I haven't tested FLV on iOS yes, however I will soon, since I'm working on something right now.

Comment: Don't forget wmode=direct. Always use it, as Flash will automatically downgrade if it is not available.

Comment: "and slugish (at best) decoding for Sorenson" - is it from actual experience? We're looking into building a real-time video chat app for iOS using Air, so Sorenson seems the only choice for us.

Comment: @jamix It seriously depends a lot on CPU power, screen resolution and video resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how the performance stacks up, but the Actionscript docs for NetStream have some information about using NetStream/Video to play video on AIR on iOS devices:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play%28%29

StageVideo is supported for H.264 video on iOS with AIR 3:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html

The takeaway is that StageVideo and limited streaming capabilities are supported on iOS devices as long as your video uses the streaming formats that iOS requires.

Comment: Ok, so basically what you say is that I could not play a .flv using an adobe air app on the iPhone ?