# Recommended video format for Ipad

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, apache-flex, air

I have an air application that I compile to run on Ipad, one of the features is to show a video about 8 minutes long. What options do I have to run it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `flv` or `H.264` for this.

Also, check out this document:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d46.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this question I posted a while a go

[Flash/AIR Stage Video on iOS - Is It Possible? How is the performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071706/flash-air-stage-video-on-ios-is-it-possible-how-is-the-performance)

You can even use stage video for best performance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static media file, just put it to http server. For iOS Devices, mov (h264/aac) is the best choice for Apple product.

If you plan a streaming resource, consider the [http live streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/).