# AS3 Flash Professional iPhone iOS app playing flv

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, flash, flv

I just coded my first iPhone app using an FLV Video using as3 in Flash Professional, but the video is really slow and choppy. Any ideas of how to increase the performance on videos for iOS?

Comment: use stageVideo  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html

Comment: OR, use the native video player (opens full screen overtop of your flash) and use mp4's instead of flv's

Comment: Do you have any code that shows how to use native video player?

Comment: There was a similar SO discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071706/flash-air-stage-video-on-ios-is-it-possible-how-is-the-performance